# How can I use a simpler link syntax in org-mode?

Tags: emacs, hyperlink, wiki, org-mode

I'd like to have links with the syntax `[[foo bar]]` go to files with the name `foo bar.org`. This would make using org-mode much more like using a personal local wiki.

Is this possible without breaking existing link functionality? I'd also ideally still be able to export to html, etc. with standard org-mode tools.

The best I've been able to do is something like: `(setq org-link-abbrev-alist '(("o"  . "file:%s.org")))`

This lets me use the syntax `[[o:foo bar]]`, but that is more verbose, and looks distractingly ugly inline. For example: `The quick brown o:fox jumps over the o:lazy_dog`. And `[[o:foo bar][foo bar]]` is even more verbose to type and edit (though it reads fine in org mode).

Comment: Bring it up on the mailing list: http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode

Comment: In case you posted this to the mailing list, could you put the link to the thread here?

Comment: The answer from the mailing list: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-02/msg00528.html

Comment: The mailing list response just suggested using snippets to make the existing process easier. But it looks this might be the path to a real solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26672609/1137803

Comment: a built-in alternative to `[[o:foo bar]]` is: `[[./foo bar]]`, which doesn't need setq, but limits to the current directory, and includes non .org files, but would work in a personal wiki style where all (and only) wiki .org files are in one flat directory; also I think it's less ugly than 'o:' and is still distinguishable from in-file links.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a ready made solution and am not a programmer, but this part is self-documenting in `org.el`, you can write a dedicated link search function. I cite:

> "List of functions to execute a file search triggered by a link.
>
> Functions added to this hook must accept a single argument, the search
> string that was part of the file link, the part after the double
> colon.  The function must first check if it would like to handle this
> search, for example by checking the `major-mode' or the file
> extension.  If it decides not to handle this search, it should just
> return nil to give other functions a chance.  If it does handle the
> search, it must return a non-nil value to keep other functions from
> trying.
>
> Each function can access the current prefix argument through the
> variable `current-prefix-arg'.  Note that a single prefix is used to
> force opening a link in Emacs, so it may be good to only use a numeric
> or double prefix to guide the search function.
>
> In case this is needed, a function in this hook can also restore the
> window configuration before `org-open-at-point' was called using:
>
> (set-window-configuration org-window-config-before-follow-link)")

See also [Hyperlinks :: Custom Searches @ gnu.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Custom-Searches.html#Custom-Searches)